# Need to hide KML Data On Fusion Table Cards in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have to create a map layer for Google maps, that when each county is clicked on the map, it displays the fuel tax rates for a year determined by a drop down menu box. I've made the maps, and I  made a table for each year, so that when the user selects a year, it simply clears out any previous layers on the map, and then sets the map with the correct layer. The problem is that when I click a county, it shows the correct tax data, but also all of the KML location data to go along with it. Is there a way to hide this in the card?

Comment: https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171216

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed a fusion tables map layer, you simply need to change the info window style on the fusion tables side of things.

1. Go to your fusion table
2. Click the tab housing your map
3. Click the tiny down-arrow next to your tab name
4. Click "Change Map" On the left side of the screen, click "Change Info Window"
5. Click "Custom" tab, and you should be able to remove the display of
   your KML data.

Comment: thanks, I tried that though and it would only work if I was viewing the table on the actual Google Maps site, it didn't change anything when I used it through the Google Maps map on my site.